# Есть ли возможность залогировать подключение?

Tags: node.js

Например, мне нужно, поднять `json-server`, и когда например я отправил запрос на сервер, могу ли как-то залогировать этот запрос в `file.txt` на стороне сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) для логирования запросов используется библиотека [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) - это легко увидеть, [заглянув в исходники](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/master/src/server/defaults.js).

`morgan` умеет писать в файл, но проблема в том, что мы [не можем](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/master/src/server/defaults.js#L40) передать в `jsonServer.defaults()` параметры для подключения `morgan`:

```
const logger = require('morgan')

...

// Logger
if (opts.logger) {
    arr.push(
        logger('dev', {
            skip: req =>
              process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' || req.path === '/favicon.ico'
        })
    )
}
```

Ну, не беда, мы же можем написать свою middleware?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const server = jsonServer.create();
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults({ logger: false, readOnly: true });

const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, '../access.log'), { flags: 'a' });
middlewares.push(
    morgan('dev', {
        skip: (req) => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' || req.path === '/favicon.ico',
        stream: accessLogStream
    })
);
 
server.use(middlewares)
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('requiest handler');
    res.header('X-Hello', 'World').json({ok: 1});
    next();
});

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('JSON Server is running'));
```

Так мы перенаправим логирование запросов в файл access.log. Код проверен.

Но только логирование запросов. Если же в лог нужно перенаправить и стандартный вывод (console.log) то тут стоит задуматься о более сложных инструментах.

---

На en.so есть вопрос, ответы на который прекрасно показывают как задружить `morgan` и `winston`

[Node.js - logging / Use morgan and winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906551/node-js-logging-use-morgan-and-winston)

```
let logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    exitOnError: false,
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)(),
        new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'app.log'})
    ]
});
logger.stream = {
    write: (message, encoding) => logger.info(message)
};

middlewares.push(
        morgan('dev', {
            skip: (req) => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' || req.path === '/favicon.ico',
            stream: logger.stream
        })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, сможете. Только логировать лучше средствами ОС. Например, в последних модных линуксах c [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) за это отвечает [journald](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)/Journal_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)). А сервер легко поднять, например, используя [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).

Comment: а чем лучше то?, и причем тут вебсокет?

Comment: Да, кто его знает. Постоянно по одной строчке записывать в файл? Может, конечно свою систему логирования напишет гораздо более эффективную, чем journald. Глядишь, и systemd заменит. Ну, а я бы печатал все в stdout, пусть ОС решает, сколько должны весить логи, когда запускать logrotate, куда отсылать алерты по панике ядра. Мне есть чем заняться чем велосипедить логи.

Comment: и чем вам ws не json-сервер? я проще чем ws модулей на npm вообще не видел.